# Error when passing arguments and convert it to hexadecimal

Tags: c++, visual-c++

How could insert text by argument and automatically transform it to hex?

I tried with:

```
unsigned char aesKey[32] = argv[1];
```

but get errors

The output would be like this:

```
unsigned char aesKey[32] = {
    0x53, 0x28, 0x40, 0x6e, 0x2f, 0x64, 0x63, 0x5d, 0x2d, 0x61, 0x77, 0x40, 0x76, 0x71, 0x77, 0x28, 
    0x74, 0x61, 0x7d, 0x66, 0x61, 0x73, 0x3b, 0x5d, 0x66, 0x6d, 0x3c, 0x3f, 0x7b, 0x66, 0x72, 0x36
};

unsigned char *buf;

aes256_context ctx;
aes256_init(&ctx, aesKey);

for (unsigned long i = 0; i < lSize/16; i++) {
    buf = text + (i * 16);
    aes256_encrypt_ecb(&ctx, buf);
}

aes256_done(&ctx);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't assign to an array variable, they're not lvalues.  Can you show what your input format looks like?

Comment: @CarlNorum: Actually, arrays are lvaues but non modifiable lvalues.

Comment: but if I put `unsigned char aesKey[32] = "hello world"` works without error

Comment: @Alok, true.  Thanks for the correction.  alexsander - initialization from a string literal is a special case.

Comment: @aleksanderhaugas, That copies the string literal into the array. You can't copy the contents of a pointer like that.

Comment: but could not use the variable in whether to pass it to another variable as in other programming languages​​?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C and C++, when you have code like

```
char name[]="John Smith";
```

The compiler knows at compile time what the size of that char array, and all the values will be. So it can allocate it on the stack frame and assign it the value.

When you have code like
    char * strptr = foo();
    char str[] = strptr;

The compiler doesn't know what the size and value of the string pointed by strptr is. That is why this is not allowed in C/C++.

In other words, only string literals can be assigned to char arrays, and that too only at the time of declaration.

So

```
char name[] = "John Smith";
```

is allowed.

```
char name[32];
name = "John Smith";
```

is not allowed.

### Use memcpy

So you could use memcpy. (Or use c++ alternative that others have alluded to)

```
unsigned char *aesKey;
size_t len = (strlen(argv[1])+1)*sizeof(unsigned char);
aesKey = malloc(len);
memcpy(aesKey, argv[1], len);
```

### The old solution

(here is my previous answer, the answer above is better)
So you need to use strncpy.

```
unsigned char aesKey[32];
strncpy((char *) aesKey, argv[1], 32);
```

Notice the routine is strncpy not strcpy. strcpy is unsafe. (Thanks PRouleau for the arg fix)

If strncpy is not available in Visual Studio then you may have to try strcpy_s (Thanks Google: user:427390)

Comment: If he's using Visual Studio/C++ then he would probably get a security error. He should use strcpy_s... see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td1esda9(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @Spundun the destination of the strcpy() should be the first parameter.

Comment: I tried your solution but the program paralyzes me when I pass the arguments

Comment: @Spundun 1) `strncpy` is unsafe. It doesn't add terminating null to destination string. So `aeskey` will overflow in your example, if length of `argv[1]` string is more than 31. 2) `strncpy` is not standard. Why not use standard equivalent: `memcpy`? 3) Anyway it's C++. There's `std::string` for strings.

Comment: Thanks kotlomoy, I made a new solution.

Answer (score 0):

In C/C++, the compiler does not automatically manipulate the arrays. You have to specify how to copy them.

The good old way is with memcpy(). A more modern way is with std::copy(). In any case, you have to validate the length of argv[1] before copying into aesKey.

For the conversion into hex, you probably have to transform a string like "AAEE3311" (up to 2*32 chars) into bytes. You should use std::istringstream and fill your aesKey position by position.

Ex:

```
std::istringstream Input(argv[1]);
Input >> std::hex >> aesKey[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine a program being called as below -

```
myprog 0x53 0x28 0x40 0x6e 0x2f 0x64 0x63
```

Inside the program I would have a loop to assign the arguments to the array -

```
const int size = 32;
unsigned char aesKey[size];
char* p;

for (int i = 1; i < argc || i < size; ++i)
{
    aesKey[i] = (unsigned char)strtol(argv[i], &p, 16);
}
```

Comment: do not quite understand, because if I replace the program freezes. but that's exactly what would need